# Let $G$ a group and let $H,K,L$ normal subgroups of $G$. Then $[HK,L]=[H,L][K,L]$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I want to prove a property of commutators in a group $G$.
Let $G$ a group and let $H,K,L$ normal subgroups of $G$. Then $[HK,L]=[H,L][K,L]$.

I have already shown that $[HK,L]$ is contained in $[H,L][K,L]$. someone can help me for the other inclusion?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely $[H,L]\le [HK,L]$ and $[K,L]\le [HK,L]$, so any product is in there also, no?

Comment: So the reason is simply because the product of any two elements of a subgroup belongs to the subgroup.Thanks!

Comment: Correct. Well done. The other direction is actually more difficult IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that the commutator subgroup is not merely the collection of all commutators, but rather the subgroup *generated* by these products. That is,
$[HK,L]$ is not equal to the set $\{[hk,\ell]\mid h\in H, k\in K,\ell\in L\}$, but rather is the subgroup generated by such products. Because of that, you easily get that both $[H,L]$ and $[K,L]$ are contained in $[HK,L]$. This holds for any subgroups (even if $HK$ is not a subgroup).

To get that $[HK,L]$ is contained in $[H,L][K,L]$, you can use certain commutator identites; e.g.,
$$[xy,z] = [x,z]^y[y,z]$$
using the fact that the groups are normal.

Answer (score 1):

In this same spirit, and Arturo's answer and remark on commutator identities, try to prove the *Three Subgroups Lemma*: if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $K, L, M$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $[K,L,M] \subset N$, and $[L,M,K] \subset N$, then $[M,K,L] \subset N$. Here $[*,*,*] = [[*,*],*]$.